# Offset datetime by years

Tags: terraform

I can get the current ISO timestamp using `timestamp()`, but the [timeadd](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/timeadd) function does not support days/months/years.

What's a good way to offset the current date by years (e.g., for setting expiry dates of a token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed no `dateadd` function yet.
Instead, regex can be used to extract the year so we can perform addition

```
locals {
  timestamp_parts = regex("^(?P<year>\\d+)(?P<remainder>-.*)$", timestamp())
  future          = format("%d%s", local.timestamp_parts.year + 3, local.timestamp_parts.remainder)
}
```

It is worth noting that there does exist the [time_rotating](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/rotating) resource that is probably better used for this purpose. This will also prevent Terraform from detecting changes every time you run `plan`, since `timestamp()` will always update, meanwhile the `time_rotating` will be smarter about it.

```
resource "time_rotating" "example" {
  rotation_years = 3
}
locals {
  future = time_rotating.example.id
}
```

References:

- https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/add-year-in-timeadd-function-or-availability-of-dateadd-function-in-tf/22977

Comment: Is there a way to extract the month as well, besides the year? Can you please post a sample where the result is the start of the next month? I am looking for this everywhere and it appears that regex is the only way. Thanks

Comment: Probably a pattern like this `^(?P<year>\d+)-(?P<month>\d+)-(?P<day>\d+)$` (add extra backslash when using in string), then you would do `x.month <= 11 ? x.month+1 : 1`

Comment: I ended up using LifeCycle to ignore the timestamp parameter from the template, thus the start date will not be changed by the timestamp() which changes eachtime the code is run with now values, redeploying my code.
The response worked for me so i won't modify it, i appreciate a second view on this (again)